# how to allow characters, space and dot in regular expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z ]+$"
```

this is my current regular expression but it does not accept .(dot). I need to use it for names. like "**Reynante A. Capco**"

Comment: What have you tried? What don't you understand? Do you know the basic syntax for regular expressions?

Comment: prefix `\` backslash for special characters. eg `\.` for dot. `\s` for space.

Answer (score 2):

The following expression gets all

- characters (a-zA-Z)
- whitespaces (\s) and
- dots (\.)

between the string beginning (^) and end ($):

The '@' is necessary to quote the backslashes inside the string.

```
ValidationExpression=@"^[a-zA-Z\s\.]+$"
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
/[a-zA-Z]|\d|\s|\.*/
```

- Any letter a-z
- Any digit 0-9
- Any whitespace
- Any dots

Comment: Try `[a-zA-Z]|\d|\s|\.*`, it's different for C#

Comment: it does not work also  ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z]|\d|\s|\.*"

Comment: ValidationExpression=@"[a-zA-Z]|\d|\s|\.*"
You need the @ so that the \'s don't need to be escaped in a string. (it tells the compiler to take this string literally).

Answer (score 0):

Validation for must contain a number, a character and a dot. Sometimes it must include a space.

For example:

```
version1.1.1-----valid
            version 1.1.1---valid
              v1.1.----------not valid(not end with dot)
             .v1.1--------not valid(not start with dot)
               v1----valid
               version 12.1.1--------valid
```

It must contain character and number dot and space are necessary
if its dot not start with dot and not end with dot